# Define field in Alfresco Association

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

We've an alfresco application in production.

We want to add an information depending on two different Alfresco models. 
Is it possible to define a custom property inside a RelationShip model?

We've already an attribute cmis:creationDate but it's not working as well. It gives us 5/1/2010.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Didn't get you -  add your model to your description & clarify what exactly you would like to achieve

Answer (score 3):

An association cannot have properties. One option to model this situation is to introduce a third node (holding the property) between the two nodes you want linked and create associations from this third node to the others.

But be warned: It may be very cumbersome to work with this model. Amongst other things, search does not support join. Hence, make sure your model supports the overall requirements in the best possible manner.